# Adding sliders from UI to pie menu

Tags: python, scripting, pie-menu

I've seen some sliders working in pie menus but the one I'm trying to add to my pie script isn't showing up. Its the 'autosmooth normals' slider from the Object Data tab, under Normals (in the Properties panel).

I'm trying to call it directly in the pie menu without making a new class since its already loaded by the main UI:

```
row.prop(mesh, "auto_smooth_angle", text="Angle", slider=True)
```

Are sliders like this one not able to be displayed in pie menus?

Comment: is the console printing out any error message? where have you seen a slider working in a Pie menu? it could help to have a look at the code of that pie menu to see how they are doing it.

Comment: Here is a link to the early pie menus attempt from several years ago.  It has an Auto-Smooth slider, the Addon code should have something for you. http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?267414-Pie-Menus-%282-66%29-Update-01-28-13.

Comment: I assume you are familiar with the following current thread?  If not... http://www.elysiun.com/forum/showthread.php?348496-Addon-Wazou-s-Pie-Menus